# How to test a ros package

Tags: ros, rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My goal is to check if a ROS package has been installed from source correctly and can work without any error.

So I'm looking for a common way to do such a test.

I've downloaded the source code of the ROS Base and some other ROS packages from the github and I can see that there is a directory named `test` in most of packages, such as `src/geometry/tf/test/`, `src/actionlib/test/`. But I don't know how to use these `test` directories.

So is there some common way to do test for each package? If there is not, does it mean that I have to read all of source code and code some test cases by myself to test ROS packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288728/how-to-test-a-ros-package/) by [bear234](https://answers.ros.org/users/22393/bear234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run all tests by calling `catkin_make run_test`. See [the catkin documentation](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/run_tests.html) for more info.

Obviously, this just runs all defined/implementes tests and cannot guarantee that it "can work without any error" (though you should be pretty safe with the core packages).

Note that you need to call `catkin_test_results` as specified on the link above to actually get the results of all tests that have run.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0